# AutoHotkey; using a modifier as a normal key and then as modifier

Tags: autohotkey

Novice on AHK here. Here are the lines:

```
^Alt:: Send, b

^!PGDN:: Send, r
```

The "^!" part of the second line gets send continuously before PGDN is pressed, and I get something like "bbbr", so I have tried:

```
Alt & AppsKey: return

^!PGDN:: Send, r

^Alt Up:: Send, b
```

Now `^!PGN::` works normally, but when `^Alt Up` is released, it fires, so I get "rb".
To clarify, I want just r, or just b, not a bundle.

Also, I plan to use other combinations of the type, with one line consisting of two modifiers and the other consisting of the same two modifiers and a normal key, so the solution cannot prevent further cases such as this one.

Comment: I don't think this can work. Can't you imagine better keys?